# Django ArrayField Default Should be a Callable

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to use postgresql ArrayField in my django project setting it a default, but I can't get rid of the warning `ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.  HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g. use list instead of []`

This is my code:

```
def get_default_subscriptions():
    return 'Noticias, Promociones, Pagos, Compras'.split(', ') # this returns a list
 
class myModel(models.model):
    # other fields
    subscriptions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), default=get_default_subscriptions()) # this is a callable, so, why the warning?
```

Docs say about this: `If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as list (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a list (such as a function). Incorrectly using default=[] creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of ArrayField.`

Can you give me an idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`default=get_default_subscriptions`** (without *paranthesis*) instead of `default=get_default_subscriptions()`

Comment: Great! thanks a lot, a bit confusing that part when they refer to callable.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit of clarification to Arakkal's answer, a callable is a function or bound method. What you passed was the return of a function call and not the function itself.
You actually called get_default_subscriptions inline instead of giving Django the function itself so it can call it when it needs to.